# Microdata for product with variations

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I'm new to microdata and I have the following scenario for which I would like some help:

I wish to put microdata on product pages where, on the page, there can be multiple variations of the same product.
Each variation has the same name, description and image but they have each their own SKU, colour, size, weight and price.

On the page I have something like

```
<section id="commonparts">  
    <h1>Product name</h1>  
    <div><img src="productimage"></div>  
    <div>Product description</div>  
</section>  
<section id="variations">  
    <div id="variation1">  
        <div>SKU 1</div>
        <div>Colour 1</div>
        <div>Size 1</div>
        <div>Price 1</div>
    </div>  
    <div id="variation2">  
        <div>SKU 2</div>
        <div>Colour 2</div>
        <div>Size 2</div>
        <div>Price 2</div>
    </div>  
</section>
```

Is it possible to microdata this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about IndividualProduct? https://schema.org/IndividualProduct

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of Microdata’s `itemref` attribute, so that you don’t have to duplicate the identical data.

Use the `itemprop` attributes on the data that is identical for all products, give each property an `id`, but don’t place these properties inside an `itemscope`:

```html
<!-- no 'itemscope' parent -->
<section>
  <h1  itemprop="name"        id="product-name">Product name</h1>  
  <img itemprop="image"       id="product-img" src="productimage" alt="" /> 
  <p   itemprop="description" id="product-desc">Product description</p>  
</section>
```

On every product (each represented by a `Product` item), you list all the `id` values in its `itemref` attribute:

```html
<section>  

  <div id="variation1" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemref="product-name product-img product-desc">
    <!-- properties specific to this 'Product' variation --> 
  </div>  

  <div id="variation2" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemref="product-name product-img product-desc">
    <!-- properties specific to this 'Product' variation --> 
  </div>  

</section>
```

Comment: Is this still the best practice for showing product variants using microdata?

Comment: @brendo234 No, I think the Schema.org vocabulary now offers specific properties for this case (e.g., [`isVariantOf`](https://schema.org/isVariantOf)).